# How is SafeNet eToken 5110 different from SafeNet eToken 5100?

Tags: code-signing, signtool, trustzone, e-token, safenet

My EV code signing certificate is expiring, and I'm thinking about changing provider. However the new provider(Trust zone) is providing a SafeNet eToken 5100, the one I have now is a SafeNet eToken 5110.

My questions are these:

- What are the differences, if any?
- Does the SafeNet Authentication Client support the SafeNet eToken 5100?

I tried finding information about the differences online, and in the SafeNet documentation, but without any luck.

Answer (score 1):

The SafeNet eToken 5110 is more recent than the 5100, it was released in 2015 while the 5100 was already available in 2011. The 5100 reached its [end of life](https://data-protection-updates.gemalto.com/files/2016/01/etoken-mask-9-eos-announcement1.pdf) in 2017

The SafeNet authentication client 9.1 [supports both](https://data-protection-updates.gemalto.com/files/2016/01/007-013386-001_SAC_9-1_Linux_CRN_RevA.pdf), the 5100 is no longer mentioned as supported in the [documentation](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjDyoPMro3-AhW4UKQEHQKKDoYQFnoECA0QAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsupportportal.thalesgroup.com%2Fsys_attachment.do%3Fsys_id%3D753cce194736dd94128dca72e36d43d1&usg=AOvVaw07WASTxciCoeuhWIQqRPcS) of the version 10.8.

These tokens support different algorithms and certifications levels. The 5110 CC for example is CC EAL5+ certified and supports RSA 4096, the 5110 FIPS is FIPS 140-2 level 3 certified and is limited to RSA 2048, like the 5100.